# Designing API to model existing Excel "stateful" application

Tags: api, api-design

I currently maintain an Excel file that has ~20 inputs which is used to modify thousands of simulations.  What I'd like to do is expose the inputs as API endpoints for both analytical developers and my own frontend.  Where I keep going back and forth on is wether or not the caller should ask for the state after each modification or the backend should automatically send it.

I'll use the simulation of an economy for example:

> backend.py

```py
@app.route("/economy/<id>/labor", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def labor(id):
    if request.methods == "GET":
         return get_labor_simulations(id)
   
    if request.methods == "POST":
         # Should this return a tiny payload, 
         # and have the frontend re-request for the state? [1]

         # > frontend.js
         # axios.post("/economy/123/labor", {"labor_growth": 0.05})
         #      .then((response) => axios.get("/economy/123/gdp"))

         econ, errors = set_labor_growth(id, request.values("labor_growth"))
         return "success" if error is None else "failed!"

         # or maybe it's better to just return the whole state [2]
         return econ.to_json() if error is None else get_original_econ(id)
```

[2] Sorry if this is to language specific, but i'm unfamiliar if passing this back will ruin some of the benefits of the modern javascript state management due as essentially i'm overwriting it every time I make a request.

Am I missing a better pattern (doesn't have to be CRUD)?

**EDIT: Answer to what's the state look like?**

With this example, the update of labor growth would update the simulations and displays of the distributions (an array converted to a histogram) of not only labor trends, but also of industry trends (another possible input) distributions, etc.  All lastly roll into GDP distributions (not a possible input).  The state I’m thinking of would then be a serialization of all these simulations.

Comment: What does this 'state' represent that you will either be returning or that the client will request? Is it just the current set of input values, or also the outputs from those thousands of simulations?

Comment: I updated the question with that answer, but the latter, the outputs from those simulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that

- the large majority of clients wants to have the updated state after posing an update to an input, and
- the amount of data in the state is not prohibitive for those clients that would immediately throw it away, and
- the calculations are performed fast enough

then it very much makes sense to return the updated state in the response of the POST request. This would give the majority of clients a reduced latency compared to sending an additional GET request.

The first two assumptions are checks that enough clients benefit and not too many are (severely) inconvenienced by the transfer of the state in a POST response.

The last assumption is more subjective, but if you would need to take measure to prevent a timeout on the HTTP connection, then I would consider that definitely not fast enough. But if the client needs to show a "please wait" indication for several seconds before being able to indicate that the request was sent successfully, that might also be considered too long by some.